# guessing game prompt asks one too many times

Tags: c++

I am getting an error saying that guess isn't defined in main. whats going on?
the prog is designed to be a guessing game

The while is only stopping because of the guess defined in main, but that makes the computer ask fore an input that isn't tested.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int nextGuess();

int main() 
{
    srand(time(0));
    int number = rand() % 100 + 1;

    cout <<" --GUESSING GAME-- \n You are to enter numbers, trying to guess rthe computer's number"<< endl;

int guess = nextGuess();
    do
    {    
    int guess = nextGuess();

    if (guess > number)
       cout <<"Your guess is to high."<< endl;

    if (guess < number)
       cout <<"Your guess is too low."<< endl;

    if (guess == number)
       cout <<"Good job, that's the number!"<< endl;
    }
    while (guess != number);

    system("pause");

}

int nextGuess()
{
    int guess = 0;
    cout <<"Please enter a number:";
    cin >> guess;

    return guess;
}
```

** Id paste the c prompt but it wont copy.

Comment: Aaaargh... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `nextGuess` twice and redeclaring variable `guess` inside the `do-while` block. Change to something like :

```
int guess;
do
{    
guess = nextGuess();

if (guess > number)
   cout <<"Your guess is to high."<< endl;

if (guess < number)
   cout <<"Your guess is too low."<< endl;

if (guess == number)
   cout <<"Good job, that's the number!"<< endl;
}
while (guess != number);
```

Comment: I thought this was wrong at first, but I tried it; it works! Thx <3

Answer (score 1):

You do call `nextGuess` twice: Once *before* the loop, and once inside the loop. Remove the first call, the one before the loop, but *keep the declaration* of the variable `guess` outside the loop and don't declare it again inside.

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop you are redefining the variable guess.  Maybe change it to something like this:

```
int guess;
do
{    
    guess = nextGuess();
```

The way you have it written now, the variable guess used in the loop is not the same variable used in the while condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use `while{}` instead of `do{}while`

```
int guess = nextGuess();
while (guess != number)
{    
guess = nextGuess();

if (guess > number)
   cout <<"Your guess is to high."<< endl;

if (guess < number)
   cout <<"Your guess is too low."<< endl;

if (guess == number)
   cout <<"Good job, that's the number!"<< endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're calling `nextGuess` twice. It's enough to declare the variable outside the loop and then call the function inside it.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int nextGuess();

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int number = rand() % 100 + 1;

    cout <<" --GUESSING GAME-- \n You are to enter numbers, trying to guess rthe computer's number"<< endl;

    int guess;

    do{
    guess = nextGuess();

    if (guess > number)
       cout <<"Your guess is to high."<< endl;

    if (guess < number)
       cout <<"Your guess is too low."<< endl;

    if (guess == number)
       cout <<"Good job, that's the number!"<< endl;
    }
    while (guess != number);

    return 0;
}
    int nextGuess()
{
    int guess = 0;
    cout <<"Please enter a number:";
    cin >> guess;

    return guess;
}
```